# Can't install R package 'mice': g++ error

Tags: c++, r, r-mice

I am unable to install R package 'mice'. I get the following error message:

```
g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -I"/usr/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include" -fpic -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
g++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-fstack-protector-strong’
g++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wdate-time’
/usr/lib/R/etc/Makeconf:143: recipe for target 'RcppExports.o' failed
make: *** [RcppExports.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘mice’
* removing ‘/home/michal/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/mice’
Warning in install.packages :
    installation of package ‘mice’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/Rtmpq8vNzo/downloaded_packages’
```

I tried to figure this out on my own but I failed. Any help will be much appreciated! Here is my session info:

```
R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

locale:
[1] LC_CTYPE=pl_PL.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=pl_PL.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=pl_PL.UTF-8    
[5] LC_MONETARY=pl_PL.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=pl_PL.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=pl_PL.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
[9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=pl_PL.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.2.3
```

I solved it by following the instructions posted by *muru* [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/466651/how-do-i-use-the-latest-gcc-on-ubuntu-14-04)

Comment: What version of g++ are you using. `-fstack-protector-strong` requires 4.9.

Comment: Im running version 4.8.5. Im not an advanced linux user so my questions may seem dull but how do I upgrade this and not crush my system? Is this command enough: 'sudo apt-get install gcc-4.9' ?

Comment: 4.9 is not the default compiler on Ubuntu 16.06 but version 5.3 is.  With that it will work.